# Laravel 4 Blade weird behaviour

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

So, i have this kind of code to print my index page:

```
class PageController extends MediaController {

protected $layout = 'layouts.main';

public function index_page() {
    $data = array();

    $data['title'] = 'Dynamic Title';
    $data['css_files'] = array(
        array('media'=>'all', 'file'=>'file1'),
        array('media'=>'all', 'file'=>'file2')
    );

    $this->layout->content = View::make('index', $data);
}
```

}

and my main.blade.php:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>

<body>
    @yield('content')
    @yield('css_files')
</body>

</html>
```

and my index.blade.php:

```
@section('title', $title)

@section('css_files')
    @foreach ($css_files as $css_file)
        <p>File: {{ $css_file->file }}, Media: {{ $css_file->media }}</p>
    @endforeach
@stop

@section('content')
    <h1>Rendered Successfully!</h1>
@stop
```

Title renders just fine, but the css file prints this:

> File: {{ $css_file->file }}, Media: {{ $css_file->media }}
>
> File: {{ $css_file->file }}, Media: {{ $css_file->media }}

instead of this:

> File: file1, Media: all
>
> File: file2, Media: all

Can anyone explain why? Thanks for the help, I'm very new to Blade.

**--EDIT--**

I already solved the problem, I happen to edit Blade syntax configuration in

> vendor\laravel\framework\Illuminate\view\compilers\BladeCompiler.php

from

```
protected $contentTags = array('{{', '}}');

    /**
     * Array of opening and closing tags for escaped echos.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $escapedTags = array('{{{', '}}}');
```

to

```
protected $contentTags = array('{=', '=}');

    /**
     * Array of opening and closing tags for escaped echos.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $escapedTags = array('{={', '}=}');
```

So I should have used {= instead of {{

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Why did you have to use `{=` ? Usually the vendors folder should not be modified because if you update it via composer your changes will be overwritten.

Comment: used to combine blade with angular.js, had to change the syntax

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1):

You are missing @stop below the title section. Try making it  like this

```
@section('title')
  {{ $title }}
@stop
```